# What packages are reporting these errors?

Tags: boot, package-management, syslog

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.5 on a laptop whose nVidia driver is not supported in 18.04 so I'm stuck here (I need the proprietary driver.)  A while ago I started getting error dialogs popping up whenever I booted this machine up.  I don't expect fixes, but I'd like to identify the failing software and reinstall or remove it.

So my question is: what packages are involved in the error messages I've identified.  BTW I see some reference to bluetooth, and AFAIK this Dell inspiron 1720 has no bluetooth hardware, just wifi.  If I'm lucky then I can just disable something that can't work anyway.

I looked at /var/log/syslog and found error reports that are probably related.   I can't tell for sure because the dialogs give no hint what actually failed, just a choice of whether or not to "report" the failure.

When I view the syslog in vim, I see red highlights on these lines.

```
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x org.a11y.Bus[1452]: ** (process:1569): WARNING **: Failed to register client:
```

and two occurrences of

```
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

and finally

```
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
```

In case more context is needed, here's the section where that occurred

```
Sep 11 20:08:37 Roisin-x ntpd[1224]: Soliciting pool server 96.126.122.39
Sep 11 20:08:37 Roisin-x ntpd[1224]: Soliciting pool server 2001:470:0:50::2
Sep 11 20:08:38 Roisin-x ntpd[1224]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.89.198
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x org.a11y.Bus[1452]: ** (process:1569): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x org.a11y.Bus[1452]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x org.a11y.Bus[1452]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x org.a11y.atspi.Registry[1584]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x systemd[1297]: Time has been changed
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x systemd[1120]: Time has been changed
Sep 11 20:08:40 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 1867 of process 1867 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 1873 of process 1867 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 1874 of process 1867 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep 11 20:08:44 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Sep 11 20:08:45 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Successfully made thread 1917 of process 1917 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep 11 20:08:45 Roisin-x rtkit-daemon[1186]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Sep 11 20:08:45 Roisin-x pulseaudio[1917]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Sep 11 20:08:46 Roisin-x dbus[679]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service'
Sep 11 20:08:46 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
Sep 11 20:08:47 Roisin-x dbus[679]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
Sep 11 20:08:47 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x dbus[679]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' unit='udisks2.service'
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x udisksd[2082]: udisks daemon version 2.1.7 starting
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x dbus[679]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x udisksd[2082]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Sep 11 20:08:50 Roisin-x org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor[1452]: Volume monitor alive
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x obexd[2108]: OBEX daemon 5.37
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x dbus[679]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x kernel: [   57.624679] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x kernel: [   57.624692] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x kernel: [   57.624701] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x dbus[679]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x org.blueman.Mechanism[679]: (blueman-mechanism:2172): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x blueman-mechanism: loading Network
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill
Sep 11 20:08:52 Roisin-x blueman-mechanism: loading Rfcomm
Sep 11 20:09:14 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Sep 11 20:09:14 Roisin-x systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
```

@Javier Ochoa, I ran the command with this output:

```
root@Roisin-x:~# systemctl disable bluetooth.service
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable bluetooth
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `bluetooth' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service.
root@Roisin-x:~#
```

When I enable wireless (via a switch that's on this laptop) and run 'rfkill list' I get

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The inxi -c 5 -b command produces

```
System:    Host: Roisin-x Kernel: 4.4.0-135-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: Dell (portable) product: Inspiron 1720 serial: 10SSGF1
           Mobo: Dell model: 0UK437 serial: .10SSGF1.CN486437CJ6132. Bios: Dell v: A09 date: 07/11/2008
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core2 Duo T7250 (-MCP-) speed/max: 1200/2001 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G84M [GeForce 8600M GT]
           Display Server: X.org 1.18.4 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           tty size: 133x78 Advanced Data: N/A for root
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX driver: b44
           Card-2: Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection driver: iwl3945
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1031.6GB (1.6% used)
Info:      Processes: 175 Uptime: 8 min Memory: 292.8/1998.5MB Client:     Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

And on reboot, the system no longer displays error dialogs when I log in.  There are errors and failures in syslog, but they are different, and maybe not important.

I'm still baffled about why turning a switch off would cause a dialog about "system program error". It's pretty distressing.

FINAL SOLUTION: reinstalling vi 'apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware' seems to have eliminated the problem with rebooting when wireless is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is not a blueman-mechanism problem.
BTW, which desktop environment are you running? It will be helpful in order to find the right solution.
Now, I will try to help you a bit.
Please, run this command on the termial:
rfkill list
The output must show you only the wifi card (Soft blocked no and Hard blocked no) and showing no bluetooth devices.
Then, could you  in the startup applications whether any bluetooth program is enable to load in the startup process?. 
Otherwise, you could take a look on the sounds preferences to see whether you have a bluethooth device engaged.
At last, you could also disable the start up bluethoot.service I mentioned before runnin this command in the terminal:
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service although you have no bluethoot device in your computer.

Comment: Xubuntu, so it's xfce4.  Rfkill shows only wireless, which is hardblocked.  The laptop has no bluetooth hardware or devices (it's too old).  I'm not sure how to find the startup processes.  I'll add the results of the systemctl command at the end of the question.

Comment: After that command, a restart still showed those errors.

Comment: Well done, try to run sudo rfkill unblock and then rfkill list. Which wifi card are you using? Could you post the output of this terminal command: inxi -c 5 -b?

Comment: I noticed that the wifi was disabled by a switch I seldom pay any attention to. I used it to unblock wifi (and bluetooth, as it happens -- I didn't know it was present.) Outputs will be appended to the question. As to the card, I have no idea, but the inxi command says it's an intel -- the output is also now in the question above.

Comment: Hi, did you try to reinstall linux-firmware

Comment: install --reinstall linux-firmware. I can see that your wifi card is supported by linux drivers in the following link [link](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlegacy). Regards

Comment: It looks like that got it.  After reinstalling linux-firmware, a reboot with wireless disabled (by switch) no longer causes error dialogs.  Thanks.